# windows server 2008 AD domain login fails

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, domain-controller

Fresh installed windows server 2008 r2 and added roles AD DS. There is one group with 5 users. while i used to login with a certain user from remote machine which is in  the same domain, the login failed and the msg appears similar as **no login instance in the server**.

Comment: Is it possible to get a bit more detail?  Is everything set up properly on the network?  Is the DC properly configured?  Are you sure you're signing on to the proper domain?

Comment: the situation is as above.The message is " there is currently no logon services in the running server".

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but you said "added roles AD DS". Did you actually run DCPROMO, too?

Answer (score 0):

When you have an AD problem, you usually have a DNS problem. Chances are the client is using the wrong DNS server, or the DC isn't using itself/other DCs as DNS servers.

Double check DNS settings on both ends. If everything looks fine, then you probably missed the problem.